# Get distinct values from xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

My sample xml looks below: I need to get the distinct states from xml. I am using xslt 1.0 in vs 2010 editor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<states>
  <node>
    <value>2</value>
    <state>DE</state>
  </node>
  <node>
    <value>1</value>
    <state>DE</state>
  </node>
  <node>
    <value>1</value>
    <state>NJ</state>
  </node>
  <node>
    <value>1</value>
    <state>NY</state>
  </node>

  <node>
    <value>1</value>
    <state>NY</state>
  </node>
</states>
```

My xslt looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
   xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">

  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="st" match="//states/node/state" use="." />

  <xsl:variable name="disst">
    <xsl:for-each select="//states/node[contains(value,1)]/state[generate-id()=generate-id(key('st',.)[1])]" >
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="(position() != 1)">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(', ',.)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:for-each>


  </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/" >
      <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$disst"/>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output: DE,NJ,NY

My above xml looks good for the above test xml.

If I change the xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<states>
  <node>
    <value>2</value>
    <state>DE</state>
  </node>
  <node>
    <value>1</value>
    <state>DE</state>
  </node>
  <node>
    <value>1</value>
    <state>NJ</state>
  </node>
  <node>
    <value>1</value>
    <state>NY</state>
  </node>

  <node>
    <value>1</value>
    <state>NY</state>
  </node>
</states>
```

It in not picking the state DE. Can any one suggest the suitable solution.Thanks in advance.
 I need to find out the distinct states from the xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your use of a predicate in your Muenchian grouping XPath:

```
[contains(value,1)]
```

This will often make Muenchian grouping fail to find all of the available distinct values. Instead, you should add the predicate to the key:

```
<xsl:key name="st" match="//states/node[contains(value, 1)]/state" use="." />
```

Alternatively, you can apply the predicate *inside* the grouping statement:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="//states/node
               /state[generate-id() =
                      generate-id(key('st',.)[contains(../value, 1)][1])]" />
```

Full XSLT (with some improvements):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="st" match="//states/node/state" use="." />
  <xsl:variable name="a" select="1" />

  <xsl:variable name="disst">
    <xsl:apply-templates
       select="//states/node
                   /state[generate-id() =
                          generate-id(key('st',.)[contains(../value, $a)][1])]" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="state">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/" >
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$disst"/>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result when run on your sample XML:

```
DE,NJ,NY
```

Comment: If I have scenario like this :<xsl:key name="st" match="//states/node[contains(value, $a)]/state" use="." />..How are we going to handle this?


  <xsl:variable name="a">1</xsl:variable>

Comment: Made the requisite modification above.